# React map data in arrays resides in an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have the following json result set taken from the axios success phase. I need to list the output of the result object of `recordResult` into unordered list's `<li></li>` elements or into `<div>`s. I have taken the values of `code` and `message`. But how can I map the data of `recordResult` and populate in the front-end?

```
`{
  "code": 1,
  "message": "success",
  "result": {
    "recordResult": {
      "red": [],
      "blue": [
        "dist: 12formats",
        "xvalue: 22formats",
        "yvalue: 88formats",
        "zvalue: dhformats",
        "tre: outline",
        "input: Non-critical"
      ],
      "green": [
        "dist: 12formats",
        "xvalue: 22formats",
        "yvalue: 88formats",
        "zvalue: dhformats",
        "tre: outline",
        "input: Non-critical",
        "on: outline",
        "up: true"
      ],
      "yellow": []
    }
  }
}`
```

Comment: `"on": outline`, `"up": true` is invalid

Comment: "up": true invalid As well

Comment: I'm happy to help, but are the things in green all supposed to be strings separated by colons or are they supposed to be key/value pairs in the json? And if they are key/value pairs are they part of a single object per pair in the array, or was the array supposed to be an object?

Comment: @AhsanAli My mistake. Updated.

Comment: @JSager Thanks.Those are strings separated by colons

Comment: @SMash What is your expected output. I mean you want each array i.e `blue,red,green,yellow` is seperate `<div>`?

Comment: @SMash do you want a list with red, green, etc. in it, and also an indented list with the contents of those colors under each one? I just want to make sure I am helping with the right thing

Comment: Also do you have access to lodash? Will make this thing a lot easier.

Comment: @JSager Yes, I need to list out all the content in a possible way. Inside <div>s or <li> tags separately in a convenient way. No, I don't have lodash access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `Object.keys` and `map`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: {
        code: 1,
        message: "success",
        result: {
          recordResult: {
            red: [],
            blue: [
              "dist: 12formats",
              "xvalue: 22formats",
              "yvalue: 88formats",
              "zvalue: dhformats",
              "tre: outline",
              "input: Non-critical"
            ],
            green: [
              "dist: 12formats",
              "xvalue: 22formats",
              "yvalue: 88formats",
              "zvalue: dhformats",
              "tre: outline",
              "input: Non-critical",
              "on: outline",
              "up: true"
            ],
            yellow: []
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }

  render() {
    let { data } = this.state;
    let results = data.result.recordResult;

    return (
      <div>
        {Object.keys(results).map(x => {
          return (
              <ul>
                <li><h3>{x}</h3></li>
                {results[x].length > 0 && <ul>
                  {results[x].map(e => <li>{e}</li>)}
                </ul>}
              </ul>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can map over recordResult by Object.keys :

```
Object.keys(obj.result.recordResult).map(function(key, index) {
  return (
           <div>key</div>  
         )
});
```

Let me Know if this Help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go dude :)

```js
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      "code": 1,
      "message": "success",
      "result": {
        "recordResult": {
          "red": [],
          "blue": [
            "dist: 12formats",
            "xvalue: 22formats",
            "yvalue: 88formats",
            "zvalue: dhformats",
            "tre: outline",
            "input: Non-critical"
          ],
          "green": [
            "dist: 12formats",
            "xvalue: 22formats",
            "yvalue: 88formats",
            "zvalue: dhformats",
            "tre: outline",
            "input: Non-critical",
            "on: outline",
            "up: true"
          ],
          "yellow": []
        }
      }
    };
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>My Items</h2>
        <ul>
        {Object.keys(this.state.result.recordResult).map(k => {
          return (
           <li key={k}>{k}
              {this.state.result.recordResult[k].length > 0 &&
               (
                <ul>
                  {this.state.result.recordResult[k].map(v => (
                   <li key={v}>{v}</li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
                )
              }
            </li>
        )})}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```